# Create a new column based on the condition of two data frames in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm new in using python. I have two data frames (DF1 & DF2) as below:

[DF1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/clycx.png)
[DF2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9hJf3.png)

I want to add a new column (copy & paste) value in column 'A' (DF1) to DF2 based on the same date. I am having trouble because the number of rows in the data frame is different, some dates in DF2 are repeated.

I wanted a result like:
[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2WeQp.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try the following:

```
pd.merge(df1, df2[['Date', 'Amplitude']], on='Date', how='left')
```